# Changing the color of a health bar texture in GLSL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsles

I am creating a 2D game using OpenGL ES 2 in Android and included with this is a health bar.  The health bar changes between 5 colors as health decreases (green, yellow-green, yellow, orange, red).  The texture for the health bar is coming from a texture atlas, and I would rather not clutter the texture atlas with a bar for each color (it would also be easier in the future to alter these colors).

This is the original green that I would like to reproduce using GLSL. The base color for this is #77ee9a.

[image]

What I've tried is to create a black and white version of the texture. The base green becomes #aeaeae here.

[image]

Then, I multiply the color I want with this black and white image.  I realized that this wouldn't work exactly right, so I took the green I wanted (#77ee9a) and divided it by its black and white equivalent (#aeaeae) before multiplying.  This resulted in:

[image]

I realized that dividing by the gray caused the green portion of the rgb value for my original green to exceed 255, creating artifacts around the bright portions of the image.

I'm not sure if there is a better way to achieve this colorizing effect, but I hope there is a solution that would allow me to.

If there isn't I would be able to create two textures, 1 pure white in the shape of the bar, and another with the transparent effects. I could then overlay these but it would require both another texture and another sprite in the game.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can compute 2 separate gradients using the GLSL mix function: one that goes from black up to the selected color, corresponding to grey values of 0 up to 0.68 (#aeaeae), and another that goes from the selected color up to white for grey values of 0.68 to 1.0.

Pass the tint color (e.g. green) in as a uniform:

```
uniform vec4 uTintColor;
```

Read the grey value and take any component (since they are all the same). Then compute where the grey value lies in each of the gradients and apply them. When it is in the lower gradient, upperGradientCol will equal uTintColor because upperGradientPos will be zero, so upperGradientCol can be used as the upper bound of the lower gradient.

```
// read grey scale value
vec4 texel = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoord);
float greyValue = texel.r;

// compute position in gradients:
float upperGradientPos = clamp((greyValue - 0.68) / 0.32, 0.0, 1.0);
float lowerGradientPos = clamp(greyValue / 0.68, 0.0, 1.0);

// apply upper gradient from uTintColor up to white:
vec4 upperGradientCol = mix(uTintColor, vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), upperGradientPos);
// apply lower gradient from black up to uTintColor:
vec4 lowerGradientCol = mix(vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), upperGradientCol, lowerGradientPos);
gl_FragColor = vec4(lowerGradientCol.rgb, texel.a);
```

To make this more versatile you could pass in different colors instead of black and white as uniforms, and same for the grey value corresponding to the tint color (currently hardcoded at 0.68).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually write a shader so you just need 1 texture which gets modified in a way like: the more heath is lost, the more gray it gets
To get the color value of the "graytexture" that shall be used is:

Grayvalue = 0,299 × Red + 0,587 × Green + 0,114 × Blue

So the formula in the shader would be like:

Healthpercantage * 0.711 + 0.299, Healthpercantage * 413 + 0,587, Healthpercantage * 0.886 + 0.114